# Embedded opencv window in MFC, ERROR

Tags: opencv, mfc

I wrote code to embed opencv window in picture box in MFC. The successful state should be opencv window in the MFC and display pics in MFC. However, my code still make the opencv window flowing around. And I can't find where the problem would be. Any one can help me out?
I will appreciate it.

```
BOOL SENSEIDlg_XQ::OnInitDialog(){
CDialog::OnInitDialog();
namedWindow("VIDEO",0);
HWND hWnd_video = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle("VIDEO");
::SetParent(hWnd_video,GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_PIC1)->m_hWnd);
HWND video_parent = ::GetParent(hWnd_video);
::ShowWindow(video_parent,SW_HIDE);
return TRUE;
```

The IDC_STATIC_PIC1 is a picture box in a Cdialog.

Comment: I've already figured it out. Write out the solutions for other users who may bump into the same problems. 
    
    change namedWindow into cvNamedWindow. Apparently, C library is better than C++ here. If you guys bump into the same problem try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already figured it out. Write out the solutions for other users who may bump into the same problems. change namedWindow into cvNamedWindow. Apparently, C library is better than C++ here. If you guys bump into the same problem try this.